# How to work on small portion of big Data File in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, random, rdd, sample-data

I have got big Data file loaded in Spark but wish to work on a small portion of it to run the analysis, is there any way to do that ?. I tried doing repartition but it brings a lot of reshuffling. Is there any good of way of processing the only small chunk of a Big file loaded in Spark?.

Comment: use filter operation to select the desire portion after filter operation you will only have small portion then you can work on it. You can also use limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ## In short
>
> You can use `sample()` or `randomSplit()` transformations on RDD

### [sample()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#sample(boolean,%20double,%20long))

```
/**
  * Return a sampled subset of this RDD.
  *
  * @param withReplacement can elements be sampled multiple times
  * @param fraction expected size of the sample as a fraction of this RDD's size
  *  without replacement: probability that each element is chosen; fraction must be [0, 1]
  *  with replacement: expected number of times each element is chosen; fraction must be 
  *  greater than or equal to 0
  * @param seed seed for the random number generator
  *
  * @note This is NOT guaranteed to provide exactly the fraction of the count
  * of the given [[RDD]].
  */

  def sample(
      withReplacement: Boolean,
      fraction: Double,
      seed: Long = Utils.random.nextLong): RDD[T]
```

**Example:**

```
val sampleWithoutReplacement = rdd.sample(false, 0.2, 2)
```

---

### [randomSplit()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#randomSplit(double[],%20long))

```
/**
  * Randomly splits this RDD with the provided weights.
  *
  * @param weights weights for splits, will be normalized if they don't sum to 1
  * @param seed random seed
  *
  * @return split RDDs in an array
  */

def randomSplit(
   weights: Array[Double],
   seed: Long = Utils.random.nextLong): Array[RDD[T]]
```

**Example:**

```
val rddParts = randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2)) //Which splits RDD into 80-20 ratio
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the following `RDD` API's :

1. `yourRDD.filter(on some condition)`
2. `yourRDD.sample(<with replacement>,<fraction of data>,<random seed>)`

Ex: `yourRDD.sample(false, 0.3, System.currentTimeMillis().toInt)`

If you want any random fraction of data I suggest you use second method. Or if you need part of the data satisfying some condition use the first one.